# WCF and gSOAP - interoperable code?

Tags: web-services, soap, wcf, wcf-client, gsoap

I'm trying to write a simple WCF Server + gSOAP client proof-of-concept application using SOAP 1.2 protocol. Here's server code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://test.com")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    void HelloWorld();
}

[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://test.com")]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void HelloWorld()
    {
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var svc =  new Service1();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8201/Service1");
    ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service1), uri);
    host.Description.Namespace = "http://test.com";

    var binding = new WSHttpBinding() { Namespace = "http://test.com" };
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, uri);
    endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new InlineXsdInWsdlBehavior());

    host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior() { HttpGetEnabled = true });
    var mex = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");
    host.Open();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then I launch service and generate code using following commands:

```
wsdl2h.exe -gyf -t WS/WS-typemap.dat -o Service.h http://localhost:8201/Service1?wsdl WS/WS-Addressing05.xsd
soapcpp2.exe -C -L -w -x -i -2 Service.h -ID:\...\gsoap-2.7\gsoap\import
```

Then I compile following C++ code:

```
#include "soapWSHttpBinding_USCOREIService1Proxy.h"
#include "WSHttpBinding_USCOREIService1.nsmap"
#include "stdsoap2.h" 

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    WSHttpBinding_USCOREIService1Proxy svc;

    _ns1__HelloWorld req;
    _ns1__HelloWorldResponse rsp;
    int hr = svc.HelloWorld( &req, &rsp );
    if ( hr != SOAP_OK )
    {
        _tprintf( _T("Error: %i\n"), hr );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and this generates error 8 (SOAP_MUSTUNDERSTAND). Have anyone ever generated working WCF to gSOAP link at all? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess -a switch in soapcpp2 have fixed error 8, so the switches are now:

```
soapcpp2.exe -C -L -w -x -i -2 -a Service.h -I<...path...>
```